# How can I start the IvTune window from Petrel?

Tags: ocean

I would like to start the IvTune tool from Petrel in order to debug my OpenInventor code. Is there any way to do this? The standard shortcut Shift+F12 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We don't package the IvTune into the release build of Petrel. We actually can't.
If you want to use it, you need to get a separate Open inventor license.

Comment: Thanks. Do we also need a separate license to do unit testing of OpenInventor-based code outside of Petrel?